# Unable to call XG-Boost endpoint created in sagemaker using AWS-Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I trained an xgboost model on AWS-Sagemaker and created an endpoint. Now I want to call the endpoint using AWS Lambda and AWS API. I created an lambda function and added the below mentioned code for my xgboost model. When I try to test it, the function is throwing a ParamValidation error. Here is my code

```
import json
import os
import csv
import io
import boto3
endpointname =os.environ['endpointname'] #name of the endpoint I created in sagemaker
runtime = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Recieved Event: "+json.dumps(event,indent=2))
    data=json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    print(data)
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpointname,ContentType='text/csv',Body=data)
    print(response)
    result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
    print(int(float(result))) #sagemaker xgb returns bytes type for the test case
```

The test event I created is dict type. The function is throwing  `Invalid type for parameter Body, value: {'Time':'7'}, type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object`
It means I should pass either byte or bytearray instead of dict type into my event. But when I read this [AWS Lambda doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html) It says that my event type can only be dict,int,list,float,str, or None type. I followed the steps mentioned in [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/call-an-amazon-sagemaker-model-endpoint-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/) aws doc to create my lambda function. Can someone please explain why my code is throwing above mentioned error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data=json.loads(json.dumps(event))` is a redundant operation. `data=event` will return `True`. The event we provided for the test case is of type dict. It has a key value pair. key can be anything and the value should be a single string of all the predictor variables separated by comas. For predicting the output, we need value of the test case. So declare, for example, `payload=data['key']` then change `Body=payload` inside `response`. Then it will work.